# Vue.js "emit event" don't bubble up to parent and grandparent element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, event-handling, event-bubbling

I want to `emit` an custom event to bubble up from the grandchild through the child element to the parent element. But it doesn't work. Even to trigger the event directly on the parent nor the child element does not work.

```html
<div id="example-app" >
   <parent>
      <child>
         <grandchild></grandchild>
      </child>
   </parent>
</div>
```

Here the Component Code:

```js
Vue.component('parent', {
    template: ` <div @testevent="test" style="padding: 10px; background-color: red; border: 1px solid black;">
                    <button @click="$emit('testevent')">Parent Button</button>
                    <button @click="test">Triggger Test Manueally</button>

                    <slot ></slot>
                </div>`,
    methods: {
        test () {
            alert('Test ok')
        }
    }
})

Vue.component('child', {
    template: ` <div style="padding: 10px; margin: 5px; background-color: green; border: 1px solid black;">
                    <button @click="$emit('testevent')">Child Button</button><br>
                    <slot></slot>
                </div>`
})

Vue.component('grandchild', {
    template: `<div style="padding:10px; margin: 5px; background-color: white; border: 1px solid black;">
                <button @click="$emit('testevent')">Grandchild Button</button>
                </div>`
})

new Vue({
    el: '#example-app',
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```js
Vue.component('parent', {
    template: ` <div style="padding: 10px; background-color: red; border: 1px solid black;">
                    <button @click="$emit('testevent')">Parent Button</button>
                    <button @click="test">Triggger Test Manueally</button>

                    <slot ></slot>
                </div>`,
    methods: {
        test () {
            alert('Test ok')
        }
    },
    mounted: function() {
      this.$on('testevent', () => {
        this.test()
      })
    }
})

Vue.component('child', {
    template: ` <div style="padding: 10px; margin: 5px; background-color: green; border: 1px solid black;">
                    <button @click="$emit('testevent')">Child Button</button><br>
                    <slot></slot>
                </div>`,
    mounted: function() {
      this.$on('testevent', () => {
        this.$parent.$emit('testevent')
      })
    }
})

Vue.component('grandchild', {
    template: `<div style="padding:10px; margin: 5px; background-color: white; border: 1px solid black;">
                <button @click="$parent.$emit('testevent')">Grandchild Button</button>
                </div>`
})

new Vue({
    el: '#example-app',
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="example-app" >
   <parent>
      <child>
         <grandchild></grandchild>
      </child>
   </parent>
</div>
```

Comment: So events don't bubble up to the root element? You have to hand the event to the parent and from there forward to the parent element until you have it where you want to?

Comment: Yes, events bubble up only up to the parent.